# Primary key validation after Django's sqlsequencereset

Tags: django, postgresql

I've migrated a DB from a Django App from SQLite to Postgres. When I enter new data on the admin view I get an error message that the primary key already exists.

> duplicate key value violates unique constraint

I tried to resync the sequences in postgres using the following command, which generates the required SQL script.

```
python manage.py sqlsequencereset app | python manage.py dbshell
```

I still get the same error as before.

How can I check whether the sequence was resynced correctly and the next id is set to MAX(id)+1 or so?

Comment: I saw this post previously, but it didn't work with sqlsequencereset.
Apparently this command produces SQL that doesn't work with my postgres version (11.3) python manage.py sqlsequencereset app 

Therefore I had to run it manually with 
SELECT setval('tablename_id_seq', (SELECT MAX(id) FROM tablename)+1)
one after the other